# Updating Mongodb docs with an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Suppose we have this array:

`const array = [{ code:1, pw:'abc'}, { code:2, pw:'grt'}, { code:3, pw:'tpo'}, { code:4, pw:'xyz'}]`

and we have these docs in our db from model called User:
 `[{ code:1, pw:'___'}, { code:2, pw:'___'}, { code:3, pw:'___'}, { code:4, pw:'___'}]`

What's the most efficient way you'd suggest to update the pw fields from db with pws from the array at one shot (in Mongoose)? (we definitely want the codes from both arrays to match) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and efficient option will be to use a bulk:

```
const usersBulk = userModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for (const user of array) {
    usersBulk.find({code: user.code}).update({$set: {pw: user.pw}});
}
usersBulk.execute()
```

It can also be done in an update with pipeline query:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {code: {$in: codes}},
  [
    {$set: {pw: {
        $getField: {
          field: "pw",
          input: {
            $first: {
              $filter: {
                input: array,
                cond: {$eq: ["$$this.code", "$code"]}
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }}}
  ]
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v47FVn8xH3n)

But I think it might be less efficient than a bulk update.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "code": {
    "$in": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4
    ]
  }
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "pw": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              "$code",
              1
            ]
          },
          "then": "abc",
          "else": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$code",
                  2
                ]
              },
              "then": "grt",
              "else": {
                "$cond": {
                  "if": {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$code",
                      3
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": "tpo",
                  "else": "xyz"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/)

Comment: Thank you but what if the array has like 1000 items?

Comment: You can maybe use `$switch` instead of `$cond` in that case. So you can create the `update` part dynamically based on your whole array. So, for each item in your array, you would add one `branches` item. You can check the docs here with the example: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/